# Difference in the output in Java

Tags: java

I have one program in java..i am confused about the output.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
        int n=0;
        for(int m=0; m<5;m++)
        {
            n=n++;
            System.out.println(n);
        }
}
```

here output is 0 0 0 0 0

But if i write,

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
        int n=0;
        for(int m=0; m<5;m++)
        {
            n++;
            System.out.println(n);
        }
}
```

then output is 1 2 3 4 5

Why it is coming like this???

Comment: Hopefully .NET Reflector exists and I can see the IL generated code. Similar behaviour in C#. `:)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because, in the first snippet, `n++` resolves to `n` *before* the increment. So, when you do:

```
n = n++;
```

it saves `n`, then increments it, then writes the saved value back to `n`.

In the second snippet, that assignment isn't happening so the increment "sticks".

Think of the operations as follows, with the order of actions being from the innermost `[ ]` characters to the outermost:

```
[n = [[n]++]]                    [[n]++]
- current n (0) saved.           - current n (0) saved.
- n incremented to 1.            - n incremented to 1.
- saved n (0) written to n.      - saved n (0) thrown away.
```

If you want to increment `n`, you should just use `n = n + 1;` or `n++;`.

Comment: @Arindam: because you're specifically using it to set `n`, not really any different (other than the fact you're no longer using the _same_ variable) to `y = 7; x = y++`: in that case, the final values are `x == 7, y == 8`.

Comment: Yes, mostly. The compiler generates the correct bytecode and the runtime environment executes the bytecode (or compiled code if a JIT compiler kicks in). But that shouldn't really concern anyone, you should just see the "Java" beast as behaving in a certain way (as per the spec), regardless of how that's actually achieved.

Answer (score 5):

thats because you're using [post-increment](http://cplus.about.com/od/glossar1/g/postincdefn.htm) (n++) instead of [pre-increment](http://cplus.about.com/od/glossar1/g/preincdefn.htm) (++n). this line will do what you're expecting:

```
n = (++n);
```

**PS**: yes, the links explain this for c/c++, but the behaviour is the same in almost every programming-language.

**EDIT**: thanks to Prasoon Saurav and  paxdiablo, i've learned something new today. the linked sites might be wrong for c and c++, but they still explain what happens in java.

Comment: Wrong! In C and C++ the behaviour is Undefined for `n = n++` and for `n = ++n`

Comment: The behaviour of the increment may be identical (I assume that's what you were getting at) but just keep in mind that the _expression itself_ is a no-go in C or C++ - there is no sequence point between the two modifications so the result is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

`n=n++;`

The evaluation order is from left to right. 
After each iteration `n` gets assigned to 0 because `n++` evaluates to `n` before the increment.

So that's what you get as the output.

You should write `n = n+1` to get the desired output..

P.S : On a sidenote `n = n++` invokes Undefined Behaviour in C and C++. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

n++ means "return the current value, then increment".  So what you're doing is returning 0, incrementing to 1, then assigning the previous value (0) back to n.

End result - n stays 0.